# How to override an inherited class property in C#?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I learned how to inherit methods by adding `virtual` to the method in the base class and `override` in the new class. But what do I do to inherit properties?

```
class bird
{
    private virtual string fly = "Yes, I can!";
    public string CanI() { return fly ; }
}

class penguin : bird
{
    private override string fly = "No, I can't!";
}
```

This pops an error, saying that modifiers `virtual`/`override` should not be used here.

Answer (score 38):

`fly` is not a property, it is a field. Fields are not overrideable. You can do this:

```
class bird {
    protected virtual string Fly {
        get {
            return "Yes, I can!";
        }
    }
    public string CanI() { return Fly; }
}

class penguin : bird {
    protected override string Fly {
        get {
            return "No, I can't!"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I had to mark `fly` as `protected`.

But even better, I would do something like this:

```
abstract class Bird {
    public abstract bool CanFly { get; }
    public string SayCanFly() {
        if(CanFly) {
            return "Yes, I can!";
        }
        else {
            return "No, I can't!";
        }
    }
}

class Penguin : Bird {
    public override bool CanFly {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class Eagle : Bird {
    public override bool CanFly {
        get {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw the downvote now. I really didn't want to downvote you answer. Spurious mouse click? Sorry for the incovenience, I removed it.

Comment: @Luca: It's not an inconvenience, I just wanted to know if there was something wrong with my answer. Thank you for you coming back and commenting!

Answer (score 3):

That is not a property in your example, it is a field.  Try using a property, or simply marking fly as protected so it can be accessed in your subclass.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
private virtual string fly = "Yes, I can!";
```

is creating a field, not a property.  Also, in order to be virtual, your property must have access higher than 'private'. You probably want something like this:

```
public virtual string Fly
{
  get { return "Yes, I can!"; }
}
```