# C# mvc override model display name without duplicating the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, globalization, resource-files

I have myself a basic MVC project which I wish to use inside of another project, however I am having a problem with the Display name attribute.

Ok so here is what I'm trying to achieve,
My "default" mvc project has a model called "Person" and in Person we have

```
[Display(Name = "FirstName", ResourceType = typeof(PersonResources))]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "LastName", ResourceType = typeof(PersonResources))]
public string LastName{ get; set; }
```

Now in the PersonResources file FirstName has the value "First name" and the LastName has the value "Surname".

Now in my new project which references my "default" mvc project I want to use the "Person" model above, however I want to change the PersonResources FirstName value to be "Single name". Now the way I am doing it at the moment is just duplicating the whole model in my new project which to me doesn't seem right.

How can I simply override the resource file and not duplicate the whole model to just change the value of a label?

I have looked into globalization but I'm not changing a language, I just want to change the label of a model from a project I have references.

Let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: I think it would be the same as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412506/c-how-to-override-an-inherited-class-property ? You can extend it and overwrite. I would give it a shot.

Comment: Cheers for the link but I don't want to create or implement the model again. I just want to be able to create a resource file that will override the original resource file